# Magento 2: Change Order's Store View

Tags: magento2, orders, store-view, edit-order

I have two Store Views defined: 'English' and 'Lithuanian'.

Suppose that a customer makes an order in 'English' *(default)* Store View. If I printed the Invoice, it would be in English language. However, the customer needs it in Lithuanian language (it would have been in Lithuanian if he had made an order in 'Lithuanian' Store View).

**How can I (as an admin) change Order's Store View after it has been made?** Is there an easy solution? If not, what database entries should be altered?

I have also tried searching for an extension but did not succeed. Any help would be very appreciated!